# Blessing on Grace After Meals

Tags: halacha, blessing, bentching

Why is a birkat mitsvah not recited upon performing the mitsvah of the recitation of birkat hamazon?
This would perhaps be akin to the blessing upon Bitkat Kohanim as noted by @danno.

Comment: Are there any comparable cases, where we make a bracha on the mitzvah of making a bracha?

Comment: @Scimonster the bracha the kohanim make before duchening (if you see the 3 verses said afterwards as the same sort of bracha - the text of what they say seems to indicate that they are but the formulation indicates that the "bracha" is not the same sort)

Comment: why don't we make a beracha before making kiddush?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is discussed in the Sefer [ליקוטי שושנים on page 13](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pagefeed/hebrewbooks_org_48285_45.pdf).

Essentially he answers:

Since we *bless Hashem* during the Birkat Hamazon (Grace After Meals), there's no need to first bless Him before doing the Mitzva.

There's no need to make a Bracha on a Bracha, since the point of making the Bracha is taken care of as we say the actual Bracha.

Similarly we don't have a Bracha *upon reciting Kriat Shma*, since Shma is all about accepting the yoke of heaven, making the pre-blessing redundant.

Comment: "Similarly we don't have a Bracha upon reciting Kriat Shma". Actually, there are brachot before Kri'at Shema. What is their purpose / why do we need them?

Comment: That is a question you can ask the forum; they do not refer directly to Kriat Shma, if you read them carefully. Besides, they are recited even if you have already said Kriat Shma earlier.

Comment: @DannySchoemann the nature of the "birkos kriyas shma" is a machlockes Rishonim (if I recall Ramban / Rashba). presenting it simplistically is somewhat misleading.

Comment: @DanF actually it is a machlockes Rishonim what the nature of the brachos on kriyas shma are. (Ramban/Rashba IIRC). It is this machlockes that determines whether or not one says the brachos after already saying sh'ma.

Comment: @DannySchoemann R Amram Gaon says to say Asher Kiddishanu...Likro et haShema before bed if you davened maariv too early.

Comment: What does Kabolas Ol have to do with a Bracha? We say a Bracha on Hallel, which is more closely related to a Bracha.

Comment: @mevaqesh I was  just translating from the book, if somebody wants to do a better job, feel free to edit my answer or add a new one. But we pasken like I wrote, as we say Birkat KS even if we already said Shma.